# split a dataframe and create many data frames or list

Tags: r, split, combn

I want to create a list or many data.frame from a dataframe at the same time after splitting a matrix. I am using the function combn to create a matrix. 
For instance:

```
 combos<-combn(1:3, 2)
 combos
 [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    1    2
 [2,]    2    3    3
```

After I have a data frame with 3 columns.

```
col1<-c(0,2,4);col2<-c(1,3,5);col3<-c(6,7,8)
df<-cbind.data.frame(col1,col2,col3)
df
      col1 col2 col3
 1    0    1    6
 2    2    3    7
 3    4    5    8
```

Using combos I would like to get this results in data frame or list:

```
 df1
      col1 col2
 1    0    1  
 2    2    3  
 3    4    5  
df2
      col1  col3
 1    0      6
 2    2      7
 3    4      8 
df3
      col2 col3
 1     1    6
 2     3    7
 3     5    8
```

After of that,
I would want to join these dataframe or list with other dataframes or list to get this result:
using this new data dfo

```
 col1<-c('a','c'); col2<-c('b','d')
 dfo<-cbind.data.frame(col1,col2)
      col1 col2
 1    a    b
 2    c    d

 df1o
      col1 col2
 1    0    1  
 2    2    3  
 3    4    5
 4    a    b
 5    c    d  

 df2o
      col1  col3
 1    0      6
 2    2      7
 3    4      8 
 4    a      b
 5    c      d

 df3o
      col2 col3
  1     1    6
  2     3    7
  3     5    8 
  4     a    b
  5     c    d
```

I have 3000 df and 5000 dfo

Comment: `combn(1:3, 2, FUN=function(x) rbind(df[,x], setNames(dfo, names(df[,x]))), simplify=FALSE)` (assuming you want to combine numbers and letters like this)

Comment: Thanks user20650. I am wrong on the post. letters were only for example.  I want to combine numbers and numbers, (dfo are number too).Sorry, I was my first post!

Comment: No matrices were injured in this edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you can use `lapply` to loop over a list.

```
combos <- combn(1:3, 2)

col1 <- c(0,2,4); col2 <- c(1,3,5); col3 <- c(6,7,8)
df <- cbind.data.frame(col1,col2,col3)

df.1 <- lapply(1:ncol(combos), function(i){df[, combos[,i]]})

col1 <- c('a','c'); col2 <- c('b','d')
dfo <- cbind.data.frame(col1,col2)

dfo.1 <- lapply(df.1, function(x){
  names(dfo) <- names(x)
  return(rbind(x, dfo))
})
# [[1]]
#   col1 col2
# 1    0    1
# 2    2    3
# 3    4    5
# 4    a    b
# 5    c    d
# 
# [[2]]
#   col1 col3
# 1    0    6
# 2    2    7
# 3    4    8
# 4    a    b
# 5    c    d
# 
# [[3]]
#   col2 col3
# 1    1    6
# 2    3    7
# 3    5    8
# 4    a    b
# 5    c    d
```